# Write date modified to file name .csv or to column in .csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to write the date modified to a file name with python? I have a large batch of .csv files where the date modified field must be converted to the file name.

Or even better write the date modified to the csv file itself as a column.

Comment: yes you can but it seems redundant to repeat the modified date for every row

Comment: I couldn't find a topic where this is explained in further detail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: @Mark Jansen thank's, I will read that topic ;)!

Comment: As I understand it, this question is mostly about how to retrieve the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `to_datetime()` to convert the float value to DatatimeIndex:

```
from os import path
from glob import glob
pd.to_datetime([path.getmtime(fn) for fn in glob("*.*")], unit="s")
```